# How can I enable and/or disable OS X's power nap feature from within Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, power-nap

I can deal with it using some command-line commands such as `defaults write …` etc, but don’t know what the exact command and argument names to use?

Comment: Power nap is only available on certain machines, hence it would be helpful if you would add which system and OS you have. Additionally, could you edit your question such that only one question is asked at a time? Preferably only about he power nap feature, as the other one (about the cheatsheet) is not very well suited for this site. It doesn't have a single correct answer.

Comment: Bart, edited. And then where is the question on tutorial/cheatsheet suited?

Comment: Thank you. With regard to the cheatsheet: I don't think a complete list of these commands exist in the first place. Secondly such a question is not really practically answerable as it is unbounded. [Here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) it's written that you should ask practical and answerable questions. So if you run into something you would like to change (like power nap) it's fine asking a specific question. You could try [Googling](http://www.google.nl/search?q=terminal+hacks) the list though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `pmset` to change the `darkwakes` parameter:

```
sudo pmset -c darkwakes 1
```

The `darkwakes` parameter is not mentioned in the man page, but it is shown by `pmset -g` if your Mac supports Power Nap and is operating on an AC power.

`-c` is AC power (or charger or wall power), `-b` is battery power, `-u` is UPS, and `-a` is all.

You can also edit the plist directly, but you have to restart to apply the changes:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set "Custom Profile":"AC Power":DarkWakeBackgroundTasks 1' \
    /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sudo sed -i '' '/DarkWakeBackgroundTasks/{N;s/false/true/;}' \
    /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you teach me about the possible values and its meaning of the `darkwakes` parameter? (And sorry for being a bit late to be notified of your answer...)

Comment: I guess it's just 1 for enabled and 0 for disabled.

Answer (score 4):

It seems the more clearly named `powernap` option has replaced `darkwakes`, which is also now documented in the [pmset man page](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset.html). Its usage is similar e.g to disable (`0`) it for all (`-a`) power sources:

```
sudo pmset -a powernap 0
```

However it seems that, according to the latest [pmset source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-956.80.2/pmset/pmset.c.auto.html), for the time being either option will work.

Comment: `powernap` has not replaced the undocumented `darkwakes` parameter.  `darkwakes` seems to configure the actual number of permitted background "DarkWakeBackgroundTasks".  My guess is enabling powernap allows DarkWakes to happen in the first place but the `darkwakes` param allows you to control how many tasks are permitted.

Comment: If you look at the source code I linked it to it is clear that the `powernap` parameter performs the same role as `darkwakes` - both names are checked at the same if statement - both do indeed try to set the `kIOPMDarkWakeBackgroundTaskKey` and `kIOPMSleepServicesKey`.  There is also a separate `dwlinterval` that sets DarkWake linger interval.

Comment: I stand corrected!  What confused me is that the official pmset man page says "*powernap - enable/disable Power Nap on supported machines **(value = 0/1)***".  So I was a chump and believed that `powernap` only accepts 0 or 1, unlike `darkwakes` which takes an int.  But that's wrong.  Experimentally I can confirm also that setting `powernap 12`  updates `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist`  the same way `darkwakes 12` would have.  That's what I get for believing Apple's docs...

Answer (score 2):

OS X: About Power Nap
The following Mac computers can use Power Nap. Some of these computers may require an SMC update in order to use this feature.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5394